# “Triche” or “tricher” for game cheats?

Tags: terminologie, jeux

If were to say (Call of Duty Cheat) would it be "Call of Duty tricher" or "Call of Duty triche".

Is "triche" just "cheat" and "tricher" = "to cheat"

Comment: In French, I would myself simply say "cheat". (French Canadian) Example : "*Tu as un **cheat**?*"

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean with "**Call of Duty Cheat**".

If it is about single-player cheat codes, that would be ***Code [de triche] pour Call of Duty***.

If it is about multi-player hacks, that might be ***Triche (or Tricherie) dans Call of Duty***.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a cheat as a help: you may use "astuce(s)". If not it's "triche" as you said.

Comment: "Astuces" are tips. They are expected to be legal so do not match "cheat" which AFAIK always imply some rule is broken.

Answer (score 1):

`triche` => Cheat
`tricheur` => someone who is cheating
`tricher` => to cheat